# Is it possible to set a default value for sparse array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

for example, if I have this array:

```
SourceFolder[0]="inbound1"
SourceFolder[1]="inbound2"
SourceFolder[2]="inbound3"
SourceFolder[100]="inbound100"
```

And I go through it:

```
for i in "${!SourceFolder[@]}"
do
 echo "SourceFolder: " ${SourceFolder[$i]}
done
```

Is it possible to make it to return some default value for not initialized indexed (3-99)?

so, for indexes from 3 to 99 it will return, for instance, "defaultFolder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {0..100}; do
    SourceFolder["${i}"]="defaultFolder"
done

SourceFolder[0]="inbound1"
SourceFolder[1]="inbound2"
SourceFolder[2]="inbound3"
SourceFolder[100]="inbound100"

for i in "${!SourceFolder[@]}"; do
    echo "SourceFolder: ${SourceFolder[$i]}"
done
```