# change array value while looping in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

The code

```
SourceFolder[0]=""
SourceFolder[1]="inbound2"
SourceFolder[2]="inbound3"

for i in "${!SourceFolder[@]}"
do    
    if [ -z "${SourceFolder[$i]}"]; then
        ${SourceFolder[$i]} = "TEST"
    fi
done
```

`${SourceFolder[$i]} = "TEST"` - doesn't work

it says

> =: command not found

How to change value in current loop index in an array?

Comment: Have you tried without spaces: `a=b` and not `a = b`?

Comment: @cirosantilli same thing( "=TEST: command not found"

Comment: Didn't the proposed solution to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653134/is-it-possible-to-set-a-default-value-for-sparse-array-in-bash) work for you?

Comment: @devnull yes, the solution in that question is working. But in that case if array size will change I have to edit code with that additional looping, which I don't like( that's why I've decided to go in this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the first space `=` is not interpreted as an assignment. There is a [full explanation on So](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977390/1122645).

Btw `${SourceFolder[$i]}` evaluate the array element, which is not what you want to do. For instance for the first one it is the empty string.

Replaces with `SourceFolder[$i]=`

Comment: This helped! btw, it has another error in if `[ -z "${SourceFolder[$i]}"]; then` it says `[: missing `]'` why is that?

Comment: again, watch your spaces. should be `[ -z "${SourceFolder[$i]}" ]`

Answer (score 1):

You must change indexnumber in the your array:

```
ARRAYNAME[indexnumber]=value
```

ok, you have array is:

```
array=(one two three)
```

you can add count to your script for initialize and change element for array indexnumber, example:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
array=(one two three)

for i in ${array[@]}
do
  echo "$i" 
  array[$count]="$i-indexnumber-is-$count"
  count=$((count + 1))
  echo $count
done

echo ${array[*]}
```

Result:

```
bash test-arr.sh 
one
1
two
2
three
3
one-indexnumber-is-0 two-indexnumber-is-1 three-indexnumber-is-2
```